# AXIS: The OperationDesc was not synchronized to a method

Tags: wsdl, axis

So I have a webservice that gets a flag from a table in sql, which works.  I am now trying to add the functionality to set the same flag.  If I have just one input (i.e. a username OR flag value), it works perfectly.  However, if I try to have 2 elements as the input, I get the following error when my AXIS tries to deploy:

org.jboss.axis.InternalException: java.lang.Exception: The OperationDesc for setPWFlag was not synchronized to a method of PWEndPoint.

Here's a clipped version of my WSDL:

```
<complexType name="getPWFlagRequest">
    <sequence>
     <element name="alias" type="xsd:string" />
    </sequence>
   </complexType>

   <complexType name="getPWFlagResponse">
    <sequence>
     <element name="result" type="xsd:string" />
    </sequence>
   </complexType>

   <complexType name="setPWFlagRequest">
    <sequence>
     <element name="id" type="xsd:string" />
     <!-- Having this line gives the OperationDesc Synch Error -->
     <element name="flag" type="xsd:string" />
    </sequence>
   </complexType>

   <complexType name="setPWFlagResponse"/>

   <element name="getPWFlagRequest" type="types:getPWFlagRequest" />
   <element name="getPWFlagResponse" type="types:getPWFlagResponse" />

   <element name="setPWFlagRequest" type="types:setPWFlagRequest" />
   <element name="setPWFlagResponse" type="types:setPWFlagResponse" />
 </schema>
 </types>

 <message name="PWEndPoint_getPWFlagRequest" >
  <part name="parameter" element="types:getPWFlagRequest"/>
 </message>
 <message name="PWEndPoint_getPWFlagResponse">
   <part name="result" element="types:getPWFlagResponse"/>
 </message>

 <message name="PWEndPoint_setPWFlagRequest" >
  <part name="parameters" element="types:setPWFlagRequest"/>
 </message>
 <message name="PWEndPoint_setPWFlagResponse"/>

 <portType name="PWEndPoint">
    <operation name="getPWFlag" >
      <input message="service:PWEndPoint_getPWFlagRequest"/>
      <output message="service:PWEndPoint_getPWFlagResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="setPWFlag" >
      <input message="service:PWEndPoint_setPWFlagRequest"/>
      <output message="service:PWEndPoint_setPWFlagResponse"/>
    </operation>
 </portType>


 <binding name="PWResetBinding" type="service:PWEndPoint">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />
  <operation name="getPWFlag" >
   <soap:operation soapAction="getPWFlag" />
   <input>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
   </input>
   <output>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
   </output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="setPWFlag" >
   <soap:operation soapAction="setPWFlag" />
   <input>
    <soap:body />
   </input>
   <output>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
   </output>
  </operation>
 </binding>


 <service name="PWService">
  <port name="PWEndPointPort" binding="service:PWResetBinding">
   <soap:address location="@url@" />
  </port>
 </service>
```

What really baffles me is that it says it has a problem synchronizing to a method in PWEndPoint, but PWEndPoint is generated by Java2WSDL.  Here's the interface that's created:

```
public interface PWEndPoint extends java.rmi.Remote {
    public java.lang.String getPWFlag(java.lang.String alias) throws 
         java.rmi.RemoteException;
    public void setPWFlag(java.lang.String id, java.lang.String flag) throws 
    java.rmi.RemoteException;
}
```

Why is it that having 2 input parameters causes it to not be able to deploy properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root of the problem.  There was an issue with using Document encoding and how I was defining complex types.

I switched it to use RPC and modified how I was defining my SetPWFlagRequest which fixed the problem.